# SVN needs-lock checking using pre-commit hook

Tags: linux, svn

I have pre-commit script which is taken from internet. Most of the scripts fails on different scenario. I would like to have pre-commit script which would allow to commit only if the needs-lock property been set. Which is Lock-Modify-Unlock model.

I have enabled the auto-props in the client configuration and added * = svn:needs-lock=* property as well.

Most of the script I found check the needs-lock property during the time of Adding new Files.But this checking alone will not solve the issue. During the below mentioned scenarios we can avoid the lock mechanism.

1) The developer can take out needs-lock property during edit. 
2) Property can be taken out alone without modifying the file.

In the above mentioned scenarios script fails.

All ideas are welcome.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Something like the below should work.

> for y in `svnlook changed -t "$TXN" "$REPOS" |grep "^[AU]" | awk -F" " '{print $2}'`
>
> do
>   svnlook proplist -t "$TXN" "$REPOS" "$y" >/tmp/prop.txt
>
> if (grep -iE "needs-lock" /tmp/prop.txt)
>
> then
>
> ```
>     if echo $y | sed 's/^.*\///' | grep -i "\.";
>
>     then
>
>      echo OK
>
>     else
> ```
>
> echo "Not allowed to lock the folder $y " >&2;
>
> exit 1;
>
> ```
>    fi
> ```
>
> fi
>
> done

This will check whether the property is applied or not on all the files/folders before commit. In case you  need to exclude folder from this, you need to add one more condition to check whether its a folder or file and proceed accordingly.

Comment: Thanks, your help really appreciated. Sorry to ask again, how can we avoid directories as mentioned ?

Comment: Abin - I just made an edit on the above. Sorry, I didn't get any better way to check for folders. However on the above I am just checking, if a dot (.) is present, it is a file and if not, its a folder. Please post here in case you get any better way. Thanks.

Comment: Thanks, but in reality we do have folders with dot(.) And I read somewhere that, folders always have trailing slash(/) and file names doesn't. Is it possible to check this ?, if yes how :)

Comment: sed 's/^.*\///' this will remove everything before the end slash in the file. So this method will work for folders too.. and it will allow users to checkin folders with dot (.) in case you wanna allow files without dot, instead of grepping for (.) give [A-B]